# how to give an access permission to a directory for a special user using PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, apache, windows-7

I have a database which contains different users. When an Admin create a folder (using the **PHP code**)he should give the **access permission** (read and write) for a special users (the new directory can be checked just by this *user who is registered in my database*).
Is there any configuration files on which I can set the access permission for the created folder? 
I don't have a clue as to how to do this.Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: This isn't going to be a predefined function in PHP.  How are you accessing files in the directory?  You would need to include the access check with that function.

Comment: @Devon I'm creating new folders on server automatically.I'm creating the directory with a permission of 0764:`  mkdir($directory, 0764, true);` but I want that this directory should be accessed on the server for one specific person who is registred in the DB. I 'm just looking for Hints.

Comment: How are you accessing the directory and files in the directory?

Comment: I haven't understand your question. I'm just creating now the folders and looking for a way to store the users permissions in my database or something like that. so that only the authorized person could acess the folders contains by typing the url localhost/project/new_folder/file1

Comment: Okay, so your accessing the files from the URL?  Most people use .htaccess for something like this but if are looking for a PHP solution then you're going to need a combination of rewrite and a MVC like router that authenticates the user and directs the request.